# How to reuse a view that is rendered in the browser when I visit the same view next time, using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to understand this, searching in many sites. Here is something that want to achieve. In AngularJS, I have implemented the route, view and the controller. It is all working fine. But I want to reuse the view that is once loaded, ie to be stored and retrieved from the client when I visit it the second time.

Like below

step 1:

view1  --- obtained from the web server to the client

ctrl1 --- obtained from the web server to the client

step 2

view2 -- obtained from the web server to the client

ctrl2 -- obtained fro the web server to the client

step 3 ( going back to view1)

view1 -- to be obtained from the browser itself. (this should not hit the web server)

ctrl1 -- to be obtained from the browser itself. ( this should not hit the web server)

Do we need to use the storage in angularjs? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this, angular implements `$templateCache` ([see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)) by default. The template is only requested from the server the first time, subsequent calls are from `$templateCache`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to see that the view is cached in the $templateCache?.

Comment: Yes, a key-value map of cacheId and cacheitem are available through `$templateCache.info();` where cacheId is the name of the template, i.e. "index.html".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$templateCache` to store your templates after they have been loaded from the server. Then, when navigating to the view, you can check the cache to see if it exists. If it does, load from there. If not, load from the server. Here is the doc on `$templateCache`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

This is also a good tutorial on `$templateCache` and its usage.
https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial

It can be as simple as the following code for storing your templates

```
.run(function ($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put('test.html', 'Hello {{ test.user.name }}!');
});
```

They can be accessed by

```
$templateCache.get('test.html')
```

As far as the controllers, they should be cached by the browser unless you are explicitly telling it not to cache your script files.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful.